# changing current directory in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I need to access `.sql` file from sqlite exe file.

First I checked location of sqlite executable file:

```
sqlite> .shell cd
C:\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3360000
```

Since the location of my `.sql` file is not in the same location `C:\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3360000` as sqlite exe file, I used `.cd` to change the current working directory to direct to the location of my .sql file (`.cd E:\My data\Learning\sql file`

But when I checked again the location, I found that current directory is still the same as the one before I changed:

```
.shell cd
C:\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3360000
```

Only when I moved the .sql file to the same location as sqlite exe file, I could read the .sql file using .read. I can not change the current working directory to the location of my .sql file from sqlite3 exe file (using .cd MY CURRENT DIRECTORY). Did I do something wrong? Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: `.shell` runs an external process, and it can't affect the parent's working directory.

Comment: Use `.cd` or just specify the absolute path to the file. (Given the spaces, you might need to quote the argument to `.cd`)

Comment: I only used .shell to check the current working directory, not to change current working directory. Do you mean absolute path with quote like this? .cd "E:\My data\Learning\sql file\my_database.sql" "my_database.sql" is my file name. This error pops up: "Cannot change to directory "E:My dataLearningsql filemy_database.sql"

Comment: Single quotes, not double. And/or use unix-style forward slashes, not backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

use

.cd path with double quotes and forward slashed instead of backward

ans: .cd "E:/My data/Learning/sql file"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).